# MongoDB with JAVA Persistence API ( JPA)

Tags: java, mongodb

I new in mongodb , i have few question about mongodb with jpa

1) `why to use mongodb with jpa` 
2) `why to not use mongodb with jpa`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you need JPA when using MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002089/do-you-need-jpa-when-using-mongodb)

Comment: @user7294900  `Do you need JPA when using MongoDB?`  their discussion was  on ,  does we can use JPA with mongoDB not why to use mongo with jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use JPA for MongoDB since it is a document database and so there's no step for mapping Java fields to columns. You can use native Java POJO with the MongoDB Java driver and it will automatically discover and persist fields for you.

See the [Quick Start](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/driver/getting-started/quick-start-pojo/) for a demo.